Will my Baggage check through on a YYZ-YUL-DOH-TRV itinerary?
I have a booking Toronto (YYZ) to Montréal (YUL) with Porter Airlines, and then YUL to Doha (DOH) with Qatar Airways, and DOH to my final destination of Thiruvananthapuram (TRV), also with Qatar. Will my bag be checked through? It's all on a single ticket that I booked with Qatar airlines.

Difficult to say. Typically bags on a single ticket air checked through but it's never guaranteed and Porter is a bit of an oddball. According to their website they only check bags through in YUL from domestic to international if you connecting to another Porter or Air Transat flight. It's hard to tell though whether that would also apply to a ticket issued by Qatar.
If you need to know for sure, contact Qatar and ask (and hope for the best).
You bags WILL be checked through from YUL to TRV, no need to pick them up in Doha.
